# C# Reading File Line by Line and Split each File Line into Individual a separate String?

Tags: c#, twitter

**Context: I want to have a twitter application that will auto tweet each line of a file, Each tweet will be one of the lines of code. I am Using "Tweetinvi" as a reference.**

**Lets Say:** i have 3 Lines in my File, 
1st Line = Apple, 2nd Line = Banana, 3rd Line = Orange.

I want the Program to read each line and choose one of the lines, And Make It Appear in a Rich Text Box ( Only that Single Line that has been chosen) I then want it To be automatic; But i want it to also allow me To Tweet Via the List Box which once a button has been pressed it Tweets whats in the box.

Any ideas or Help would be great thank you

Answer (score 1):

To read the lines of a text file, you use the following code.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("example.txt");
```

To add the lines to a ListBox, you use the following code.

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

To operate on a particular line, you use the following code.

```
string line = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

Tweet.PublishTweet(line);
```

For RichTextBox, you could use the following code.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("example.txt");

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += line+"\n";
}
```

And to tweet this text:

```
int lineindex = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);

string line = richTextBox1.Lines[lineindex];

Tweet.PublishTweet(line);
```

Comment: What About Rich Text Box?

Comment: Just added that ^_^, may not be perfect as it's using "GetLineFromCharIndex" but I think it should do.

Comment: Thank you, I copied this but its throwing me an error; "IndexOutOfRangeException was Unhandled"  I have attached a printScreen http://prntscr.com/af8xw8 | any Ideas? Thank you for your help

Comment: Hey again; I tried something different; But when i type in even one letter, not even finishing the sentence, it automatically tweets it? Any suggestions? I want it to tweet When i click the button after i finished http://prntscr.com/afbohn

Comment: You've put the "Tweet.PublishTweet" code in the "TextChanged" event, this is why it is run every time the TEXT is CHANGED. You might wanna move this to the "button1_Click" event instead.

Comment: When i Move it, It says - the name "line" doesn't exist is current context

Comment: I'm not really sure how exactly I would format this as I don't have access to all your code, but obviously you would need to set "line" equal to something.